# Upgrade from ASP.NET Core 5.0 to ASP.NET Core 6.0

Tags: asp.net-core-6.0

Code in ASP.NET Core 5.0:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var host = CreateHostBuilder(args).Build();
        host.MigrateDbContext<YourDbContext>((context, services) =>
        {
            var logger = services.GetService<ILogger<YourDbContextSeed>>();
            new TodoListDbContextSeed().SeedAsync(context, logger).Wait();
        });

        host.Run();
    }

    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
            {
                webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
            });
}
```

I want to move this code to ASP.NET Core 6.0.

Please help me. Thanks a lot.

Comment: what exactly is your problem here?

Comment: Hi @Nguyen Duy Nhan, it seems you want to know how to convert your current code to .NET 6, pls also share how do you define the `MigrateDbContext` extension.